# Unable to Clone from Github: nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3

Tags: swift, git, macos, process

**Scenario:** Attempting to clone a secured Github repository.

I've tested the code with my personal bitbucket repository containing a test colder of text. - it works.

However when attempting to use the same code for company's GitHub repository I get the following error via console:

```
Cloning into '/Users/frelee/documents/KonyIntegrationBuild'...
2019-04-15 10:44:05.441475-0700 git-remote-https[6504:56517] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-04-15 10:44:05.670364-0700 git-remote-https[6506:56594] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-04-15 10:44:05.700772-0700 git-credential-osxkeychain[6507:56598] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 42263 of [95fbac39ba]
```

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation


//func cloneRepository() {
//    let source = "https://AmourineTech@bitbucket.org/AmourineTech/testbit.git"
//    let localTarget:NSString = "~/documents/KonyIntegrationBuild"
//    let myPath = localTarget.expandingTildeInPath as String
//
//    try! Process().clone(repo: source, path: myPath)
//}

func cloneRepository() {
    let nativeSource = "https://github.com/EastWestBank/Native-Mobile-App.git"
    let localTarget:NSString = "~/documents/KonyIntegrationBuild"
    let myPath = localTarget.expandingTildeInPath as String
    try! Process().clone(repo: nativeSource, path: myPath)
}
```

```
extension Process {
    private static let gitExecURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/git")
    private static let tarExecURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/tar")

    public func zip(source: String, archivedOutput: String) throws {
        executableURL = Process.tarExecURL
        arguments = ["-cf", archivedOutput, source]
        // emulate this: $~/workarea:tar -cf MyStuff.zip MyStuff
        try run()
    }

    public func clone(repo: String, path: String) throws {
        executableURL = Process.gitExecURL
        arguments = ["clone", repo, path]
        try run()
    }
}
```

What does the following mean?

```
2019-04-15 10:44:05.441475-0700 git-remote-https[6504:56517] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-04-15 10:44:05.670364-0700 git-remote-https[6506:56594] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-04-15 10:44:05.700772-0700 git-credential-osxkeychain[6507:56598] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 42263 of [95fbac39ba]
```

BTW: I also get the following via console:

```
2019-04-15 10:44:05.700789-0700 git-credential-osxkeychain[6507:56598] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:42263: (0) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0
2019-04-15 10:44:05.735647-0700 git-remote-https[6508:56602] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor]
remote: Enumerating objects: 275, done.        
remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/275)           
remote: Counting objects:   1% (3/275)           
remote: Counting objects:   2% (6/275)           
remote: Counting objects:   3% (9/275)           
remote: Counting objects:   4% (11/275)      
...
```

Comment: What happens when you run the same code from the command line? Do you always use HTTP to clone?

Comment: I always use the HTTP to clone.  That pattern works with the commented-out 'test' 'cloneRepository' code.  I don't understand what is happening 'under the covers'; where a simple test case works but the 'real' case doesn't.  BTW: it's partially working... it was counting objects.